Initializing the Color Using Hex Code in SwiftUI
I have the following function defined in the SwiftUI Color extension.
 init(hex: String) {
            // Remove '#' if exists
            var cleanedHex = hex
            if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
                cleanedHex = String(hex.dropFirst())
            }
            
            // Convert hex to RGB
            var rgb: UInt64 = 0
            Scanner(string: cleanedHex).scanHexInt64(&rgb)
            
            let red = Double((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            let green = Double((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
            let blue = Double(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0
            
            self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue)
        }

I call the function as shown below:
color = Color(hex: "#34C759")

And I print the color:
print(color)

It outputs:
#34C759FF

Why does it add extra FF in the end? This messes up my SwiftUI view and now the color is not correctly selected?

In general the last 2 values of a hex RGBA color represent its alpha value. FF Would be 100% tho so it should not change the colour unless you compare it to a color that does not have an alpha of 100%. How does it mess with the View?

How would I compare the SwiftUI color structs? How can I find out if two colors are equal?

The simple answer is Colour conforms to Equatable so you can do a direct comparison.  But I suspect that is missing some nuance for your situation?

@johndoe if you just need to compare them for testing purposes once to figure out if they are the same I would just print both to the console like you did. The same hex values should correspond to the same color being displayed unless they do not have an alpha value of 100%, then it would depend on the color behind as well.
